# What is wrong with my if else statements for this program?

Tags: java, if-statement

For some reason my code won't run, saying that I have a few errors.

```
//ask for user input for the selected vehicle

if(choice == 'A' || 'a') {
    System.out.println("How many miles would you like to drive the van?: ");
    milesDriven = input.nextInt();  
} else if(choice == 'B' || 'b') {
    System.out.println("How many miles would you like to drive the honda?: ");
    milesDriven = input.nextInt();
} else if(choice == 'C' || 'c') {
    System.out.println("Here are the statuses of your cars!\n");
    Garage.printCarStatus();
} else {
    System.out.println("That is an invalid choice!");
}
```

Comment: Try `if(choice == 'A' ||  choice == 'a')`

Comment: _saying that I have a few errors_ . What errors are you getting? Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

Change conditions in your code from -

```
if(choice == 'A' || 'a') // the OR operation is not applicable of char values
```

to

```
if(choice == 'A' || choice == 'a') // boolean operands using OR
```

Comment: Thanks, one other thing that I was curious about if you have time. The only other errors I have in my code are the two I surrounded with stars. Do you have any idea what I did wrong?

Comment: @BeenisProgramming Can not see any stars

Comment: @BeenisProgramming Few things over that. 1. Please don't link code. 2. Try and segregate consequent errors. 3. Share the errors that you face with that portion of the code.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know how else to share it properly. The errors I am facing for the first example (input.nextChar.at(0);) is "1 error
Mac:Desktop apple$ javac Garage.java
Garage.java:69: error: cannot find symbol
   choice = input.nextChar.at(0);" 
                 ^ The second error is "symbol:   variable nextChar
  location: variable input of type Scanner
Garage.java:85: error: cannot find symbol
    Garage.printCarStatus();
          ^
  symbol:   method printCarStatus()
  location: class Garage".

Comment: Both of these seems to be because you have not declared the field prior to using it and `Garage.printCarStatus` is also either missing the class or the static method expected within it

Answer (score 1):

You are using if condition incorrectly. "||" operator is acted only upon binary values or booleans. The correct way to write your code would be

```
if (choice == 'B' || choice == 'b') {
     ... your code here
}
```

Comment: It's not, I am just slow at typing :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to my comment above,

I suggest you simplify your code by converting to upper or lower case

```
if ('A' == Character.toUpperCase(choice)) {
}
else if ('B' == Character.toUpperCase(choice)) {
}
```

// etc

Answer (score 0):

you can use your if statement like as,

```
String mychoice=String.valueOf(choice);

if(mychoice.equalsIgnoreCase("A")){
    //your code here
}
```

here you do not care about lowercase or uppercase char value.